# Typescript: get target type of class property in runtime

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following classes for Example and want to transform a ApiResponse (JSON) to my Type:

```
class Item_Project {
  public statusAktive: boolean;
  public ProjectName: string;
  public ProjectNumber: number;

  public static fromJSON(jsonObject: Object){
    let t_Project: Item_Project = new Item_Project();
    for(let index in jsonObject){
      if(t_Project.hasOwnProperty(index)){
        if(jsonObject[index] !== undefined && jsonObject[index] !== null) {

          // i need a type check for t_Project[index] here
          // typeof t_Project[index] returns the type of the value not the accepted type

          t_Project[index] = Helper.getTrimmedValue(jsonObject[index]);
        }
      }
    }

  }
}

abstract class Helper {
  public static getTrimmedValue(value): undefined|string|number|boolean {
    // does some magic
  }
}
```

is it possible to check what kind of type the t_Project[index] property accepts to convert to the right property on the commented position?

Comment: Types don't exist at runtime (except emitted decorator metadata, but that's different story). The actual solution depends on what is Item_Project and what these 'types' really are.

Comment: Can you explain better? You already know the types of your `Item_Project`.